# can't get field permission granted on facebook api 4.0.1

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using

```
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

to access my profile data on my app (I've accepted the app's specific request for permission to [get my primary email address](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#permission-email))

I don't get any email field on the response. It works with any test user I create, though. What am I missing?

Even more weird: When I run

```
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/permissions');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    var_export($graphObject);
```

I get:

```
Facebook\GraphObject::__set_state(array(
   'backingData' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'permission' => 'public_profile',
       'status' => 'granted',
    )),
  ),
))
```

How come the email permission is not even on the list, when I have explicitly added it to "requested permissions" on the app's settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Graph Explorer here to see what you can/should get back: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

email is listed under the Extended Permissions tab.

How did you log the user in?  You should pass in the scopes including 'email' to the getLoginUrl method.

Comment: I was precisely doing just that at the moment. The email is right there!

Comment: (or the permission, for that matter)

Comment: I don't see where you're asking for the email permission, that part wasn't provided.

Comment: Where's your code which asks for the 'email' permission? Are you sure it's being granted correctly by your user(s)?

Comment: you are right: the problem was in the getLoginUrl call (posted an extra answer complementing yours to explain). Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Had to switch

```
$helper->getLoginUrl();
```

for

```
$helper->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope' => 'email'
    )
);
```

('scope' must contain all permissions on a comma separated list)

Comment: I cannot see, where you would use this code in your above question... Could you give more details please?

Comment: For fully functional example code, check my PR (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/pull/54) on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/f1916f3a1e8aeece518a18dc88f05775aadb9840/examples/login-logout-get-profile  Particularly: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/f1916f3a1e8aeece518a18dc88f05775aadb9840/examples/login-logout-get-profile/redirect-login.php. The team rejected it, but since they haven't submitted any complete examples yet I think it's the best learning by example code right now.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this in SDK 4-dev and is working

```
//permissions request
$request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/me/permissions'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObjectPermissions = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
//echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObjectPermissions,1 ) . '</pre>';

$permissions = [];//create permissions array

foreach ($graphObjectPermissions as $key => $permObject) {
    $permissions[$permObject->permission] = $permObject->status;
}

//check for email permission
if (array_key_exists('email', $permissions ) &&  $permissions['email']=='granted') {
    echo '<pre> email permission granted </pre>';
} else {
    echo '<pre> email Permission denied </pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)

Answer (score -1):

see the 90 line in FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php ... it looks like

public function getLoginUrl($scope = array(), $version = null)

I change by

public function getLoginUrl($scope = array('email'), $version = null)

and works!!!

Regards!!!!